# How do I suppress the huge stack trace after a rake TestTask failure?

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm setting up a rakefile for a project, and I've defined some rake TestTasks. I ran a simple sanity test that does an `assert_equal(1, 2)` just to check the output, and, in addition to the usual failure output, I get this mess:

```
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby -w -I"lib:." "/usr/lib/ruby/...]
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:993:in `block in sh'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1008:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1008:in `sh'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1092:in `sh'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1027:in `ruby'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1092:in `ruby'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/testtask.rb:115:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1110:in `verbose'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/testtask.rb:100:in `block in define'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:605:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:594:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

How do I get rid of it? I don't want to have to scroll up past 20 lines of junk to see my test failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rake shouldn't be returning a backtrace in this situation -- the error is with the external command, not rake's internals.  I've sent a email to Jim Weirich regarding the following patch: https://gist.github.com/1003628

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you and solved it by updating rake: `gem install rake`

This updated from whatever I had to 0.8.7.

I'm running 1.9.2-p180 (OS X, installed with Homebrew) and was running tests on a newly created project (made with Hoe).

Comment: Bizarre enough, I still add trace being printed on `0.8.7`. Updated to `0.9.2` fixed the problem on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Rake normally does not show a backtrace unless you specify `--trace`. Perhaps you have configured Rake to always run in `--trace` mode?

> By default, rake does not print out the stack trace if you get an error in the code that rake calls. You can get the stack trace by running with the --trace flag, but usually I'd just rather see it anyway. You can do that by putting Rake.application.options.trace = true into the rakefile.

If not, you might try setting `Rake.application.options.trace = false` in your Rakefile.

Comment: AFAIK, I don't have tracing enabled - no `--trace` flag, and I tried setting the option as you mentioned - same result.

Answer (score 1):

I still had unwanted stack traces in rake 0.8.7, updating to 0.9.2 finally helped for me (ruby 1.9.2p180 [i386-mingw32] on Win7 32bit).

Comment: I too updated from `0.8.7` to latest (`0.9.2`) and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb`

You should be able to add something like

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer { |line| line =~ %r{/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb} }
```